# How can I let the user load/play their own songs in XNA?

Tags: xna, xna-4.0

I made a song player program using XNA 4.0 and I was wondering if there is a way to allow the user to play/load their own songs. I can play songs from a list that I make but I want the user to be able to play their own songs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have the user select a file.  The song class can be instantiated using the file name:

```cs
Song usersSong= Song.FromUri(@"file:///" + openFileDialogue.FileName);
```

If you want them to have options for more than one song, you will have to manage the playlist yourself.  Try getting them to identify a folder, getting all of the file names from that folder, and loading those file names into a list.  You can then iterate through the list every time the xna mediaplayer raises the event that a song has finished playing.

With some elbow grease and creativity you can come up with some interesting ways of using a users music.

Comment: It's worth pointing out that the mediaplayer most likely already uses some form of streaming and that there is no way to instantiate a Song from a stream.  You will have to use the song files URI exclusively.

Comment: Ok so I've looked through the FromUri method in the song class and I am confused about what you've entered for the parameter. Can you please explain?